# Trying to run python with VS code - "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get python to work with VS code and struggling hard.

I've installed multiple version of python previously and have uninstalled them all and reinstalled with the latest version of anaconda. Link to a screenshot of the problem below. I'm only just getting back into coding for the first time in years. It's going to be something stupid.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `C:UsersGodziAnaconda3python.exe` should probably be more like `C:\Users\Godzi\Anaconda\3\python.exe`. Not sure if you've set that path yourself, but the path is broken. And if you're new to Python (no idea of your history) i'd probably start out with just regular Python, not Anaconda. Unless your end goal is to learn machine learning as your first project.

Comment: Brand new to python. Done a bit of C back in the day and matlab.

Machine learning is my first project.

I haven't set the path myself, Not sure exactly how to change it. I checked the settings and it looks good there.

https://imgur.com/a/YM0otOf

Comment: Add python to the path variables.

Comment: @Reef Sadly I always run my Python code in a vanilla terminal, but as Abdullah says, check so that your executable is in your `$PATH` in windows. Might work :)

Comment: Python interpreter was placed in a new location in the status bar. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999975/vs-code-cant-find-python/72230168#72230168).

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution:

1. If you're not using Code Runner: Per [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12173#issuecomment-640926281), you need to go to settings (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to do so) and type "Python Terminal Execute in File Dir". Then tick the first checkbox that shows up and you're done.
2. If you are using Code Runner: Go to settings and type "Code-runner: File Directory as Cwd" into the search bar. Then tick the first checkbox that shows up and you're done. You don't need to do step one of my answer, but you can if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I use extension Code Runner to run Python code inside Visul Studion Code. This extension run your code in "OUTPUT" instead "TERMINAL". To run the code you need to select it and click shortcut "CTRL+Alt+N".