# Visual Studio Code can't find Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, visual-studio-code

I have had a huge issue with Visual Studio Code for the past many weeks. One day Visual Studio Code didn't manage to run any Python file. I have the message:

> bash: C:/Users/rapha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe: No such file or directory

I have uninstall Python and Visual Studio Code many times to add properly Python 3.8 to my Windows path, but I have always the error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: There are a lot duplicates for this problem. What is the canonical question?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with Windows (C:/Users/ ... python.exe)? This can only be on Windows. Though, why is it Bash that says that? [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)? [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)? [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)?

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio Code, open the *Settings* with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) then search settings for "Interpreter." There will be an option for "Python: Default Interpreter Path." Set the location of your *python.exe* file. Open a **new** Visual Studio Code terminal with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) to test the
Python command; you may need to restart Visual Studio Code.

I had trouble with Visual Studio Code being unable to locate Python even though I could run Python commands from any terminal opened from my computer (<kbd>Windows Logo Key</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>). I noticed that the Scripts folder was not installed on my Python installation, so I reinstalled Python and followed the above steps. It worked for me.

Visual Studio Code has a [Python tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) as well which includes a **Select a Python Interpreter** section (*[Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)*).

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Visual Studio Code preferences, and under interpreter, you'll find `Interpreter Path`, so set that to the path of your Python installation, restart Visual Studio Code, and you should be good.

Comment: It didn't work. It's really weird. I have reinstall Python in a know folder, I'm sure it's in it. I set my path in VS code but same issue

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried just running the code from the terminal in Vs code each time? As in `python3 myfile.py`

Comment: It works if I type python3 myfile.py. It's weird

Comment: Ok, now type `python3 -v`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, but I found a different solution;

In file *settings.json* I had
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "D:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe", but even this was getting ignored for some reason!

So, I looked at $ENV:path in the PowerShell loaded in Visual Studio Code, and the $ENV:path in the standard command line PowerShell in Windows, and they were different!

It seems that if you have a terminal open in Visual Studio Code, it remembers the $ENV from that terminal, even if you completely restart Visual Studio Code or even if you reboot your computer.

What worked for me (by accident) is, close all terminal windows (and possibly anything else terminal/PowerShell related that's open) and give it another try!

If it still doesn't work, compare the $ENV:Path values again, and see if they're still different!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have also [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) installed and WSL is my default terminal. Visual Studio Code was open in a Windows environment, but since the terminal was defaulting to WSL and WSL has its own Python installed in the */usr/bin/* directory, it was failing to run the python file. So *if* you are using a Windows environment, be sure your terminal is [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or PowerShell. Or if WSL is opened, be sure changing the interpreter to */usr/bin/python*.

In both cases it worked for me.

Comment: Use inline code formatting for paths

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter was placed in a new location in the status bar. Just go to the corner and select the appropriate interpreter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, close Visual Studio Code and open Visual Studio Code again. Now run the file again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
Switch from "Run code" to "Run Python file".

There is also a third option, "Debug Python file".
In the upper right corner of Visual Studio Code, a down arrow next to a play button.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and literally tried every possible solution, but, and this issue happened because I messed up with the Visual Studio Code files and deleted some of its related files.

Thankfully, I could finally solve the issue by *downloading Visual Studio Code and installing it without uninstalling my current installed Visual Studio Code* and this added the required missed files and fixed it.

Visual Studio Code download link: [Download](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Python and reinstalled (after checking the box - Add to `PATH` variable). This resolved the error

Comment: On what platform?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for opening the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) (
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), and selecting the Python interpreter.

You can also check:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

In your Python interpreter when it's installed.

Add the path to environment variables:

Go to *System Properties* → *Advanced* (or type "system env" in the start menu).

Click *Environment Variables*, add "PATH" and add the outcome of `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`.

Comment: What platform? It sounds like [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) ("System Properties" and "start menu"), though it could also be some Linux distribution.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention, it's a possible solution for a problem with windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have python installed on Linux.

I did:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 ~/bin/python
```

That create's a symbolic link. And to find out where your executable `python` or `python3` file is you can simply use `which python3`.

Now I don't need to change setting in vsCode. In my case that changes did not have any affect or I could not chose the interpreters location. So I came up with a pragmatic solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too when I downgraded to 3.8 from 3.11
Here's how i fixed it.

If you are using Code Runner, just go to Files>Preference>Settings and search for Code Runner: Executions. Open the settings.json and find python. You should see "python -u" as default value. Then change it to "py -u".

I dont know the reason but it seems like VS Code can't access python command on its terminal but py does.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. My solution was simply that I didn't have a python exe installed (only python3) but my terminal was in my user environment. I had forgotten to switch over to the django project virtual environment using `pipenv shell`

Answer (score -1):

I have installed [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and it works perfectly. I'm happy. It doesn't fix the issue, but it's a great alternative.

But the issue came back.

Comment: Edit : after restarting my computer the issue came back :(