# Visual Studio Code cannot recognize Python interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

## Problem

My VSCode extension `Python` doesn't recognize the Python interpreter I have installed on the computer. I can use the terminal to run code but when I use Jupyter Notebook, it doesn't recognize it. I have tried many ways like [finding questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999975/vs-code-cant-find-python#:%7E:text=In%20VS%20Code%2C%20open%20the,need%20to%20restart%20VS%20Code.), [searching the document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), changing the path, changing the environment variables, reinstalling Python and the extension... But it seems useless. Before I upgraded to version 3.10.4, I still managed to use and the VSCode extension was still recognized. Any idea about my problem? Sorry for my bad English.

[image: Python version]

## Error

[image: Error]
[image: Extension]

## Update:

I have reinstalled everything and it remained the same. But I have found an issue that when I typed `python --version` and `python3 --version`, it printed two different versions. I have deleted all `Python 3.9.11 version` folders before.

[image: Different versions]

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the linked thread? `In VS Code, open the Settings with (Ctrl+,) then search settings for "Interpreter." There will an option for "Python: Default Interpreter Path." Set the location of your python.exe file.` When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: @NickODell I have tried it and nothing happened. It cannot still recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, I left it for about one month. After updating my VSCode to the latest version `1.67.0`, everything goes smoothly again. I changed to the [standard install path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments): `C:\Python\Python310\python.exe`. Before that, I tried the solution from two guys who answered my question but it didn't work.
[image: Interpreter]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a cache problem, could you try to delete the caches under:

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User
```

Like this:

[image]

Empty the `globalStorage` and `workspaceStorage` folder.

Answer (score 1):

First, Python version 3.10.4 is not the problem. I just installed and tested it with the the following versions:

```
Windows: 10.0.19044 x64
Python: 3.10.4 x64 bit
Jupyter Notebook server: v6.4.10
Jupyter Lab: v3.3.2

VS Code Version: v1.65.2 x64 ZIP (portable)
VS Code Python Ext (Microsoft): v2022.2.0
VS Code Jupyter Notebook Ext: v2022.2.1030672458
```

Second, your problem description is too general for a pinpoint solution so let's do it the hard way:

Completely uninstall Python and VS Code. Use an uninstaller like [BCUninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/) (free/Open Source) or [HiBit Uninstaller](https://www.hibitsoft.ir/) (free) to remove any residual files and registry entries. If you need to keep/reinstall Python packages, create a PIP requirements.txt file before starting the uninstall.

Download fresh copies of Python and VS Code.
**Make sure they have the same/right bitness (x86/32-bit or x64/64-bit)**

Install Python
PIP install Python packages (Jupyter, etc)
Install VS Code and Python extentions

Start VS Code and test - should work now. If not, then please update your question with specifics about your setup and configuration.

Comment: always use a virtual environment to prevent polluting the Python install